# AWS Golden Image from VMware to AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to know if it's a good idea to make a CentOS AWS golden image in VMware and then export it to AWS format (AMI) using the AWS Import/Export service?

I'm asking this because AWS might tweak the CentOS kernel parameters for their infrastructure and when you export it to AMI you might lose this optimisation.